# Does groovy have date literals?

Tags: java, groovy

Following code does not work -

```
new Date(2011-10-01)
```

What is the format of specifying date literals in Groovy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no concept of a "date literal" in either Groovy or Java.

See the [Java Date API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and/or the [Groovy Date API](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html).

If you want to create a date from a string, you need to [parse it](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29) (or use [DateFormat.parse()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29)), or use [Groovy-style dates](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/08/groovy-goodness-working-with-dates.html).